# Calculate probability from infinite tree

Tags: probability

Jacob is contemplating what ice cream flavor he wants for he can only choose one of the three flavors chocolate, orange or pear. Jacob is very indecisive; he wants chocolate from the beginning but there is a $50$% chance that he will change his mind to another flavor before making the final decision. If he changes his mind, he will choose one of the other two flavors at random. Say he changes to pear, then there will once again be a $50$% chance that he changes his mind before making the final decision (i.e. this process could repeat infinitely). What is the chance that in the end, he will have chosen chocolate flavor?

**My Solution:**

Due to symmetry I would argue that the probability that he chooses orange is the equal to choosing pear, hence we will only try and compute the probability that he chooses pear and get our answer out of that.

Now if we look at a fraction of the probability tree drawn out below. Let brown, yellow and green circles represent chocolate, orange and pear respectively. Black horizontal line means that he changes his mind and red crosses is the final decision. Furthermore, we will refer to the distance between two adjacent objects (connected with a line segment) as a “*path*”. Note that every path in the tree describes a $1/2$ chance of choosing that specific route.

[image]

We observe that, if we stand on an arbitrary green circle, we can make it to another green circle if we move over 4 paths. If we choose point $P_1$ as our starting point, we may describe the possible routes probability as $(1/(2^{3+4n}))2^n$ for any non-negative integer $n$. That is because, from the initial chocolate point, it takes $2$ moves to the first green $P_1$, then $4n$ moves more to get to any other green point on that side of the tree, and finally $1$ more move to reach the final decision. We then multiply with $2^n$ because the tree splits and creates more routes leading to green points. Similarly, if we choose $P_2$ as our starting point, then we have $(1/(2^{5+4n}))2^n$ for some non-negative integer $n$. We calculate the limit of the sum:
$(1/(2^{5+4n}))2^n + (1/(2^{3+4n}))2^n = 0.17857142857142855$.
We get that the chance of Jacob choosing chocolate is $0.6428571428571429$.

**Question:** Is the answer correct/reasonable and does there exist more sophisticated methods to calculate the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a different answer.

Here’s a simpler method. Let $p_c$ be the probability that Jacob ends up choosing chocolate; notice that the probability of him ending up at either of the other two flavors are identical and equal to $\frac{1-p_c}{2}$.

Jacob has a $1/2$ probability of not switching at all, so we have
$$p_c=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(\text{chocolate | his mind changes at least once})$$
If he changes his mind once, we are now in the same situation as before, but with one of the other two flavors. Given that he switches once, the flavor he switches to will then have a probability $p_c$ of finally being selected, and chocolate will have the probability $\frac{1-p_c}{2}$ of being selected. This implies that
$$p_c=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1-p_c}{2}$$
and, solving this equation, we have
$$p_c=\frac{3}{5}$$

---

Consider a more general version of this problem in which there are $n$ ice cream flavors (hopefully, none of them is pear flavored) and a probability $p$ that Jacob changes his mind after each choice. Using the same method as above, I calculated the following formula for the probability that his final choice is the same as his initial choice:

$$p_c=1-\frac{p(n-1)}{p+n-1}$$

Comment: I think you are in the right. I understand how the same “choosing process” repeats itself and I fancy the idea of how you use that fact, but I am uncertain if I fully understand the way $P$(chocolate | at least change his mind one time) functions.I belive it works like this:

Comment: Assuming $p_c$ is the probability that he ends up with chocolate, $p_c = ½ + P$(chocolate | at least once…). “atlesat once…” is for me the complement to not changing his mind, which is $1/2$. Therefore we multiply $1/2$ with the chance of getting chocolate, i.e. $p_c$ = $1/2 + 1/2P$(chocolate). Why this works is because, the “atleast once…” also cover the cases of which he whould change his mind 3000 times etc. Then you assume that the way to get chocolate is by changing his mind one time (exactly), to put the equation togheter.

Comment: Was this how you solved the problem? And should we get $p_c=3/5$ if we assumed that he got chocolate after changing his mind 2 times instead of one, if so, how do you form that equation?

Comment: @Hassebae Yeah, that all sounds right. If we know that he changes his mind twice, then there is a probability of $1/2$ than he will decide on chocolate after two switches and a probability of $1/2$ that he will decide on something else after two switches. This means that the probability of eventually coming back to chocolate is given by $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot p_c+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1-p_c}{2}$$
which is indeed equal to $p_c$ as you predicted.

Comment: yes, $p_c = 1/2 + 1/4(1/2 * p_c +1/2 * (1-p_c)/2) = 3/5$. So to summarize, with this method, regardless of how many times he changes his mind (therefore we might aswell assume $1$ time), we always end up with $3/5$. Thanks.